Flutter android application will not connect to external url api. Connects to local internal ip api only- ios works
I am using vscode on a mac and have a Flutter app that needs to connect to a url api eg: www.test.com
When testing using an internal ip eg: 10.0.0.3:80/api/Values/ the app connects fine and posts and receives data,
when testing externally using the url, the app fails with the following error : network is unreachable, No address associated with hostname.
Code :
Future fetchAndSaveNotificationData() async {

 String? registrationHexNumber ="0";


try  {     
 


  // Replace with your username and password
  String username = 'UserName';
  String password = 'PassWord';

  
  // Encode username and password using Base64 for Basic Authentication
  String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));

  final url = Uri.parse('http://www.test.com/api/Values/');

    print(' over here 01 ${url.toString()}');


  final response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': basicAuth,
    },
    body: jsonEncode({
      'registrationHexNumber': registrationHexNumber,
    }),
  );

    print('over here 02 ${url.toString()}');


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Decode the JSON response
   
    }

    
  } else {

  }
}   catch (e) {
  print("Error: $e");
    }
}

the issue seems to be here:
print(' over here 01 ${url.toString()}'); // i get up to here


  final response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': basicAuth,
    },
    body: jsonEncode({
      'registrationHexNumber': registrationHexNumber,
    }),
  );

    print('over here 02 ${url.toString()}'); // i do not get here. 

I can access the api url via the emulator web broswer and a physical device used for testing. So the url is active and the connection is not blocked.
I do have the relevant permissions such as:

android.permission.INTERNET

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE


This seems to be only an issue with Android.  Tested iOS and works as expected.
The emulator has the necessary internet access.
Edit: Added the following to do a connection test from the app:
Future<void> testConnection() async {
  try {
    print('Testing connection...');
    
    // Try to resolve the domain
    print('Looking up domain...');
    final addresses = await InternetAddress.lookup('test.com');
    print('Domain resolved to: ${addresses.map((a) => a.address).join(', ')}');
    
    // Try to ping the first address
    if (addresses.isNotEmpty) {
      final socket = await Socket.connect(addresses.first.address, 80,
          timeout: Duration(seconds: 5));
      print('Successfully connected to socket');
      await socket.close();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Connection test error: $e');
  }
}

Output:
I/flutter ( 8850): Testing connection...
I/flutter ( 8850): Looking up domain...
I/flutter ( 8850): Domain resolved to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
I/flutter ( 8850): Successfully connected to socket


Granting internet permission alone isn't enough.
You must also ensure you're connected to the internet on the emulator and make sure the "Airplane mode" is not on.
Airplane Mode Off
Internet Connection Status

The problem occurs on both emulator and a physical device. Data and wifi is enabled and airplane mode is off.
